# Create instance of model with field with choices

Tags: python, django, django-models

Lets consider this model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    DEFAULT = 1
    NOT_DEFAULT = 2
    SOMETHING = 3
    SOMETHING_ELSE = 4

    CHOICES = (
        (DEFAULT, 'foo')
        (NOT_DEFAULT, 'bar')
        (SOMETHING, 'tar')
        (SOMETHING_ELSE, 'oof')
    )

    field1 = models.CharField(
        max_length=128,
    )
    field2 = models.SmallIntegerField(
        choices=CHOICES,
        default=DEFAULT
    )
```

how to i fill it with this data?

```
name, status
'one', 'foo'
'two', 'oof'
'tree', 'foo'
'four', 'foo'
'five', 'tar'
'six', 'bar'
```

that does not work since it's expecting an integer

```
MyModel.objects.create('one','foo')
```

how do i do it properly without stupid workarounds?

is there a build in mapping like

```
'foo' -> 1
'oof' -> 4
```

etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the tuple of tuples `CHOICES` and you need to find first element by value of the second. So you can generate dict from tuple and get value, for example:

```
value = 'foo'
{v: k for k, v in MyModel.CHOICES}.get(value)
```

Comment: that's what i call "stupid workaround". Is there really no build in solution? seems like a common problem to me. Someone exported data to text using `get_FOO_display()` and now i need to reverse it...

Comment: i don't know best solution, you have the tuple of tuples `CHOICES` and you need to find first element by value of the second.

Comment: still haven't come up with anything better :( . Marking this as an answer and moving on :/

Comment: Python taught us to elegant solutions, but sometimes it happens.

Answer (score -1):

[According to the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#choices), when you define a set of choices:

> The first element in each tuple is the actual value to be set on the model, and the second element is the human-readable name. For example:

Your `field2` expects an integer. It will store that integer, and use the value it's paired with to determine the human-readable value to use for display. With your current setup for instance, a value of `1` maps to `foo`.

Consider:

```
m = MyModel.objects.create(
    field1 = 'MyText',
    field2 = 1
    )
```

The value stored in the database for `m.field2` is `1`, but the human-readable name to be used in forms etc. for `m.field2` is `foo` because of how you have defined your `CHOICES`.

Answer (score -1):

You can modify your model to achieve desired result.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    DEFAULT = 'foo'
    NOT_DEFAULT = 'bar'
    SOMETHING = 'tar'
    SOMETHING_ELSE = 'off'

    CHOICES = (
        (DEFAULT, 'foo')
        (NOT_DEFAULT, 'bar')
        (SOMETHING, 'tar')
        (SOMETHING_ELSE, 'oof')
    )

    field1 = models.CharField(
        max_length=128,
    )
    field2 = models.CharField(
        choices=CHOICES,
        default=DEFAULT
    )
```

Comment: no i can not modify this model, i have a huge csv and i need to parse it.